# what is this message I get when I start bash?

Tags: bash, shell

When I start bash, it says `ubuntu@ubuntu-Inspiron-3593:~$` and then just blinks. What is this? What does it mean?

I am completely new to the `bash` shell and I don't know what I'm looking at, I don't know what information it is trying to tell me.

What is it telling me?

Does this thing have a name? Why does it exist?

Comment: Try to redirect its output into a file, e.g. `bash &>examine.this.file`

Comment: You are using live installer. First ubuntu is your user name/id. After an install you will see the user name you select. After @ is the system name `echo $HOSTNAME`. You assign those during install here: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#9-create-your-login-details You can see user id just by typing in `id` at the terminal line.

Answer (score 5):

> When I start `bash`, it says `ubuntu@ubuntu-Inspiron-3593:~$` and then just blinks

This is the prompt. You've started a shell, `bash`, and it's telling you that it's waiting for instructions. The prompt string can be customised, and this particular one (probably) tells you that you're logged in as a user `ubuntu`, that your machine is named `ubuntu-Inspiron-5393`, and that you're currently in the your own personal directory (probably `/home/ubuntu` but conveniently abbreviatied as `~`) without any particular administrative privileges (`$` rather than `#`).

If you are more used to Windows, then the `bash` session you've opened is much like starting `CMD` or `Powershell`. No graphics; just text. And that you're in the equivalent of your `C:\Users\user` folder.

At the prompt you can type commands. For example `date` (to show the current date/time), and `ls` (to list the files, directories, and other items in the current directory). Each time you've finished a command you need to hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to tell the system you want it to process the command you've typed. Often you'll get no response at all except another prompt - UNIX/Linux systems tend towards being terse and don't usually tell you "yes, done that" except by not complaining.

Comment: Maybe you also add a short note about `PS1` variable.

Comment: @aviro IMHO, that would be useful if one wanted to change the prompt, but in this case it may just confuse matters.

Comment: @aviro I'd prefer not. That could be a follow-on question if needed, but there's nothing wrong with the default